# Cordova Facebook plugin build fail and in browser not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova, phonegap-facebook-plugin

following the next link http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/ I type the next line

> cordova plugin add https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"

with a the plugin locally. After doing that, the ionic build faild

```
2 warnings and 1 error generated.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:    CompileC build/AppName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppName.build/Objects-normal/i386/FacebookConnectPlugin.o AppName/Plugins/phonegap-facebook-plugin/FacebookConnectPlugin.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (1 failure) Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args:
-xcconfig,/Users/braianmellor/Desktop/AppName/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,AppName.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,AppName,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/braianmellor/Desktop/AppName/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/braianmellor/Desktop/AppName/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch`
```

So I decided to go with

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable
>   APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"

And it work's perfectly, but when I add inside the .config of the file app.js  this lines

```
var appID = 123456789;
var version = "v2.6";
$cordovaFacebookProvider.browserInit(appID, version);
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
ReferenceError: facebookConnectPlugin is not defined
```

When to index.html and add 
And now I'm getting

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'browserInit' of undefined
```

Need some help here please. The official plugin for ngController can't build and the secondary one can't use it on website :(